# Does Borderlands 2 have a special Developer's chest

Tags: borderlands-2

Borderlands 1 had a [special developer's chest](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rust_Commons_West#Hidden_Loot) that had a high chance of dropping above average loot. Does Borderlands 2 have a similar chest?

If it does, then there are some follow up questions:

1. Where is it?
2. Does it remain a good chest on the second play-through?
3. Are there more of these developer chests?

Comment: Have you seen the **golden** chest?

Comment: Yes I have. This is not the same. The golden chest isn't lootable repeatedly.

Comment: Made the title a bit clearer.  As a sidenote, interesting link text.

Comment: Consider it an easter egg. Bonus points if you get the reference ;)

Answer (score 2):

After looking around. I found some youtube links that show there is a chest hidden in the same way as the borderlands 1 chest.

In the map Tundra Express, from the fast travel point. Keep the glacier on the left, and start walking past it. You should walk directly past a varkids camp. And eventually you will reach a open cliff, with a end of map turret on the right (and a varkids camp). Drop down from the cliff to reach the chest. It is under the border turret. Be careful not to jump outside of the map.

Ps: enjoy the view, the train rushing by is nice.

The chest is however not as badass as the borderlands 1 chest. So it contains few overlevelled guns, and purple or orange rarity weapons. It does contain a bit better loot than normal in my limited experience. (I found my first non-quest relics there).

So far I do not know if it remains a good chest, or if it is the only one. And I'm not totally sure it contains uber badass loot.

Answer (score 1):

The Tundra Express chest everybody keeps talking about is false. It is a good chest yes, and will likely give you loot relative to your level/suggested level of story mission. But the only legitimate DevChest I've seen was actually in Three Horns Divide. Go to the far left corner of the bandit camp near the first Catch-a-Ride and keep walking along the rock off the map, you won't be shot and you will find a Portable Toilet. I got purples off of this every time so far.

Comment: Why is yours a dev chest, but the one mentioned almost two years ago isn't?

Comment: Do you have a source for this info?

Comment: @Frank in borderlands 1 there was a chest that gave WAY to high loot, and that was called the dev chest for some reason (by some sources, one of these sources I learned the chests location from. So that is why I called it the devs chest. It is not official iirc.). This would just be a similar chest. So not suprised if this toilet is the devs toilet or something. ;)

Comment: Found the toilet, but it only dropped lvl 11 greens for me, while I was lvl 30. (so it acted like a normal toilet). Still, a cool find that one. A very out of the way location.

Answer (score -3):

There is a very good chest if you go to arid nexus badlands when u get in to the little town there there is a ammo station on top that building is a chest witch has the claptrap unit next to it from number one

Comment: This isn't what the question is asking for, I'm afraid, therefore your post could be deemed as 'not an answer'.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Texenox sadly it seems there is no dev chest at all in borderlands 2. However with the huge amount of golden keys you can get (look on steam for a list of possible keys). It isn't really needed. There is enough good loot to find.